# Corda : Trader-demo - database observations

Tags: corda

I have been investigating trader-demo process using debugging and looking at database on side(buyer & seller). I have noticed following in database at the end of running runSeller demo when it finishes running TwoPartyTradeFlow. Please help understand.

https://discourse-cdn-sjc1.com/standard2/uploads/corda/original/1X/4249978e55f7e37dca53163546374a25644d5f64.png

Questions:

Why the commercial paper output of last transaction is not propagated to both databases (Seller & Buyer)? Seller only sees cash output in the vault table and Buyer sees commercial paper output and cash output unspent cash.

Why seller’s CP_STATES table would not see the final output? Shouldn’t both database contain same entries?

Answer (score 0):

The purpose of a node's vault is to allow it to easily identify the states it has available to consume. It will only store states in the vault that it may possibly be able to consume in some way later on.

In the case of cash, only the owner is able to consume it, so only the owner of the cash will store the state in its vault. In code, this is implemented by making `Cash.State` a subclass of `OwnableState`.

Both nodes should still see the transaction in their transaction storage.